# Paying early for google speech to text api, would i be able to use $300 credit?

Tags: speech-to-text

When I'm trying to authenticate my card with Google cloud I'm getting this error.

> Your card doesn't support automatic recurring payments [QR-CC3ST-02].

I got my otp and I had successfully authenticated.

I also got message from my bank saying that my authentication is successful.

Still Google is keep saying above error.

Now my card isn't verified.

So my $300 credit is still unused. Now, if I do a pay early option and buy credit for some amount, would I be able to use that $300 credit?